# How to import all functions from subdirectory into the main environment through the __init__.py file?

Tags: python, import, module, nose

I have a the following directory structure:

```
mymodulename
    | mymodulename
    | mymodulename | __init__.py
    | mymodulename | io | io.py
    | mymodulename | io | __init__.py
    | mymodulename | io | data_type | tables.py
```

In the following file, I was successfully able to do: 
`| mymodulename | io | __init__.py`

```
from .data_type.tables import *
```

and can now  call like this: `mymodulename.io.some_function`

However, I can't seem to do the following in `| mymodulename | __init__.py`

`from .io import *`

It works, when I start python and do `mymodulename.some_function` but it doesn't work when I run `nosetests`

I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodulename.io'`

Comment: From which directory are you running `nosetests`?

Comment: I was running `nosetests` in the `mymodulename/tests/` directory.  Is this the wrong one?

Comment: Do you mean `mymodulename/tests` or `mymodulename/mymodulename/tests`?

Comment: yes sorry about that.

Comment: If I run it from `mymodulename` directory it works! if you can add the answer i will select it as correct.